# Change default path for when I SSH in to CentOS server?

Tags: centos, ssh, sshd, home

I have a CentOS 5.7 web server, and I want to change the default place I land in when connecting using SSH.

Currently I land in `/home/username`, and I want to land in `/home` instead.

I've gone in as root and added `PermitUserEnvironment yes` to `/etc/.ssh/sshd_config` - and as I understand it this then sweeps the user's own `ssh` folder for an `environment` file. What I'm not sure about is exactly what I'm adding to this environment file, as `export path=$PATH:$HOME` doesn't seem to work, either here or in my .bashrc or .bash_profile files (which as I understand it wouldn't make a difference anyway as an SSH connection is a non-interactive shell?).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using PAM for authentication, which is probably the most likely. As root head into `/etc/passwd`.

There you should see your username and path! Change it there and you are home free!

EDIT - Sorry it just occurred to me that you maybe didn't want to change your home folder. In that case, simply add:

```
cd /home
```

To the bottom of your `.bashrc` file!

Comment: It's better to use `usermod` when changing anything concerning a user that writes to `/etc/passwd`, to prevent mistakes: `usermod -d /home user`.

Comment: That side comment about `.bashrc` made me facepalm. It's so simple and obvious, wish I had thought of it! Good job. Kudos!

Answer (score 6):

The thing to remember is that `~/.ssh/environment` is read before a shell or `ssh` command is spawned, so (for example) neither export nor $PATH make sense.  You can only set environment variables (not run general shell commands) here.

If you grab the environment for a non-interactive ssh shell, then modify that, you should get what you want for non-interactive commands.   For example:

`$ ssh mylogin@myserver  env`

will give you what the ssh starts with on your server.   If you write your `~/.ssh/environment` file as:

`PATH=/usr/local/bin`

and rerun the above, you should get "bash: env: command not found".   Good!

Now, build up your path explicitly, based on what it was at base from your system's `sshd` (i.e. the first "ssh .... env" call), for example (adding `/usr/local/bin` at the head):

`PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Note also that it is not useful to try to set the CWD in `~/.ssh/rc` (which is run after `~/.ssh/environment` is read, but before your `ssh` shell or command) as your shell will start (by default) in your home path.

Comment: double +1, I was looking everywhere for this information