# A question about shell and .profile,.bash_profile,.bashrc

Tags: bash, shell, aix

I'm on aix 7.1, my shell is bash

- If i did

  ```
  ssh ibmunix 
  gqlplus  user/pass
  ```

  All works and `gqlplus` starts. `gqlplus` is on `/opt/freeware/bin`
- If i did from another machine

  ```
  ssh ibmunix "gqlplus  user/pass"
  ```

  I get the error message

  ```
  gqlplus: command not found
  ```
- If i did

  ```
  ssh -t  ibmunix "source .bash_profile; gqlplus  user/pass"
  ```

  it works fine.

The question is: is possible with `ssh` to read automatically `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Check `sshd`'s man page, and the section `Login Process`.

Comment: I have add PATH in .ssh/environment but nothing change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution
first enable on sshd_config user environement

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

Then edit $HOME/.ssh/environement
and put PATH and whatever you want

The $HOME/.ssh/environment file can't contain other than variables and comments
for example
good environment file content

```
HOME=/home/user
PATH=$PATH:/opt/freeware/sbin:/bin:/opt/freeware/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

bad environment file content

```
source $HOME/.profile
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```

The permission must also correct otherwise don't work
correct perms are 0700 for .ssh and 0400 for .ssh/environment

```
ls -lhd .ssh/
drwx------ 2 username username 4,0K nov  4 16:29 .ssh//
ls -lhd .ssh/environment
-r-------- 1 username username 73 nov  4 16:29 .ssh/environment
```

The proof that works.
On Linux the command sed_64 doesn't exist, it exist on Ibmaix remote machine on /opt/freeware/bin dir.

```
ssh linuxmachine sed_64
bash: sed_64: command not found

ssh remoteaix sed_64
Usage: sed_64 [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...

  -n, --quiet, --silent
                 suppress automatic printing of pattern space
  -e script, --expression=script

.....
```

WARNING: the .ssh/environment is read before .bashrc and .bash_profile using ssh so if you don't put the correct PATH you will not find some commands, even if correct path is set on .bash_profile, .bashrc

WARNING: This configuration is safe only on home-private environment, don't use on production/serious places. Because the option PermitUserEnvironment allow any user to bypass their login shell and any ForcedCommand.

Comment: FYI `PATH=$PATH:...` doesn't work for me at all. If I set this and try `$ ssh host 'echo $PATH'`, it prints a literal `$PATH` (and anything else results in `command not found`). Explanation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60683/176219).

Comment: Works fine for me on Linux Slackware current, with sshd default configuration, tried now `ssh remote  'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games      echo $PATH 
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib64/openjdk/bin:/usr/lib64/openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib64/qt/bin:/usr/lib64/qt5/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin` I tried now on AIX

Comment: Weird. FWIW my server is latest Debian stable with OpenSSH version 1:7.9p1-10+deb10u2.

Comment: Probably something wrong in your configuration, I have tried now on debian buster with ssh 1:7.9p1-10+deb10u2 and works fine `ssh remote 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

Comment: tried also on AIX, works perfect

Comment: I have also improve my answer and test all now, works fine

Comment: Thanks for following up. It's still not working for me, so I [posted a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618073/) to try to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @RyanLue The "proof" does not prove that `$PATH` is expanded in `PATH=$PATH:/opt/freeware/bin:...`, only that the `PATH` is set to that value. If you have a directory named *literally* `$PATH` in your current directory, commands will be looked up in it, too. Try with `mkdir '$PATH'; ln -s /bin/uname '$PATH/cat'` ;-)

Comment: This answer is dangerous; sysadmins should not enable `PermitUserEnvironment` because that will allow any user to bypass their login shell and any `ForcedCommand`, and break a lot of implicit assumptions made by ssh itself, other software and other sysadmins.

Comment: If you're able to user `PermitUserEnvironment` in the server's configuration, then you're also able to use `SetEnv` and set whatever environment variable you like.

Comment: I have improved the answer with the security consideration of user414777, thanks for the warning.