# .ssh/environment: Is variable expansion (PATH=...:$PATH) supposed to work or not?

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, path, sshd

I've just discovered `~/.ssh/environment` and the `PermitUserEnvironment` setting in OpenSSH Server. It works great for setting variables to literal strings; *e.g.:*

```
# host ~/.ssh/environment
PATH=/home/rlue/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

```bsh
# client
$ ssh host 'echo $PATH'
/home/rlue/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

but variable expansion does not work:

```
# host ~/.ssh/environment
PATH=/home/rlue/.local/bin:$PATH
```

```bsh
# client
$ ssh host 'echo $PATH'
/home/rlue/.local/bin:$PATH
```

I've found multiple questions that address this topic, with differing answers about whether variable expansion *should* work or not:

- ["I figured it out, it was not expanding because I added a line `PATH="$PATH:/new/path"` to my `~/.ssh/environment` when it should have been `PATH=$PATH:/new/path`"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332532/332534#comment1017561_332534)
- ["You have double quotes, variable expansion and an alias definition. None of that will work."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8078350/4865822)
- ["`~/.ssh/environment` is read before a shell or `ssh` command is spawned, so (for example) neither export nor $PATH make sense."](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60683/176219)
- ["proof that [it] works"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203961/176219)

The author of that last post said he confirmed he got it working with the same version of OpenSSH server that I'm running (1:7.9p1-10+deb10u2 on Debian stable), but I followed his directions to the letter and I'm still getting a literal `$PATH` (*i.e.,* no variable expansion).

Does anyone have a definitive answer re: whether it's *supposed* to work, and if so, what my configuration is missing?

Comment: You should not enable `PermitUserEnvironment` -- that's a very dangerous setting which allows users to bypass their login shell and `ForcedCommand`, and may also trip other security assumptions. Users can safely and easily set environment variables in their initialization scripts, there's no need to use `PermitUserEnvironment` at all, ever.

Comment: Same goes for [`AcceptEnv`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/612495/414777).

Comment: If your intention is to set an envvar *only* in shells run via `ssh`, you can do it with `if [ "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]; then export PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar; fi` or similar.

Comment: @user414777: Given "ssh host command", which user initialization scripts are used before the command is executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the source code, the relevant functions are [`read_environment_file()` in `session.c`](https://salsa.debian.org/ssh-team/openssh/-/blob/debian/1%257.9p1-10+deb10u2/session.c#L880) and [`child_set_env()` in `misc.c`](https://salsa.debian.org/ssh-team/openssh/-/blob/debian/1%257.9p1-10+deb10u2/misc.c#L1900). These are simple functions - just read lines of the form `var=value` and set them, checking for limits and validity, but without doing any additional processing of the values. That's also what [the manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/openssh-client/ssh.1.en.html#ENVIRONMENT) says:

> Additionally, ssh reads `~/.ssh/environment`, and adds lines of the
> format “`VARNAME=value`” to the environment if the file exists and
> users are allowed to change their environment.

So, no, it's not supposed to, going by documentation or by code.