# How to set PATH when running a ssh command?

Tags: bash, ssh

Assuming user has `/bin/bash` as the shell in `/etc/passwd`. Then `ssh user@host command` runs the command using Bash. However, that shell is neither login nor interactive, which means neither `~/.bash_profile` nor `~/.bashrc` is sourced. In that case how to set the `PATH` environment variable so that executables can be found and executed? Is it recommended to prefix the actual command with `source ~/.bashrc`?

---

Edit. This question is trivial for Bash, because (as people pointed out) `~/.bashrc` *is* sourced in such case. The definitive answer comes from this paragraph in `man bash`:

> Bash  attempts  to  determine  when  it is being run with its standard input connected to a network connection, as when executed by the remote shell daemon, usually rshd, or the secure shell daemon sshd.  If `bash` determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists  and is  readable.   It  will not do this if invoked as `sh`.  The `--norc` option may be used to inhibit this behavior, and the `--rcfile` option may be used to force another file to be read, but neither rshd nor sshd generally invoke the shell with those options or allow them to be specified.

Comment: `.bashrc` is sourced, but it probably has a test for interactivity at the top. Things you put before that check should apply, and that's what I do to force PATH when the server doesn't allow user environment or use `~/.pam_environment`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have few possibilities:

- Set the `PATH` on the server in `~/.ssh/environment` (needs to be enabled by `PermitUserEnvironment yes` in `sshd_config`).
- Use full path to the binary
- As you mentioned, manually source `.bashrc`: prefix the command with `. ~/.bashrc` (or `source`)

It pretty much depends on the use case, which way you will go.

Comment: Manually sourcing `~/.bashrc` is not necesary, it happens by default. It fact, it seems to me like a bad idea.

Comment: `$PATH` does not expand from `~/.ssh/environment`, at least not in `OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019`.

Comment: @Jaakko It is probably disabled in sshd_config using `PermitUserEnvironment` (default in recent versions)

Comment: I figured it out, it was not expanding because I added a line `PATH="$PATH:/new/path"` to my `~/.ssh/environment` when it should have been `PATH=$PATH:/new/path`

Comment: Actually after trying probably everything (that I had rights to fiddle with) the . ~/.bashrc worked for me accessing with SSH an old Solaris system from a bash script run in MSYS2 on Windows.

Comment: On MacOS Catalina OpenSSH_8.1p1 be warned you better do `$ echo "PATH=$PATH" > ~/.ssh/environment` cause `$PATH` does not expand

Comment: FYI using `~/.ssh/environment` doesn't work for me at all. If I set `PATH=$PATH:...` and try `$ ssh host 'echo $PATH'`, it prints a literal `$PATH` (and anything else results in `command not found`). Explanation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60683/176219).

Answer (score 9):

You are equating *local* settings to *remote* settings.

Locally, a bash instance, the present running shell in which you write:

```
ssh user@host command
```

Will execute the command ssh (nothing more) as a client ssh.
To do so the *local* shell needs **not** to start a sub-shell or a new shell or login.

The command is executed as a `ls` command is: locally.

It is the client ssh command that opens a network connection to a *remote* system, where, if correctly authenticated, a **new** shell will be started to execute the command written as an argument to ssh, or, if no argument is given, expect further commands on that connection.

That new *Remote* shell necessarily will be a login shell as the remote user (to that system) needs to be authenticated to login. Or, if some specific command is given, just run such command with the authenticated user privileges.

You could see which files are sourced by adding a `$file sourced` to the start of each file (in the **remote** system)(root is needed to change `/etc/` files):

```
$ a=(~/.bashrc ~/.profile /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile)
$ for f in "${a[@]}"; do sed -i '1 i\echo "'"$f"' was read"\n' "$f"; done
```

And then just start a ssh console:

```
$ ssh sorontar@localhost
/etc/profile was read
/etc/bash.bashrc was read
/home/sorontar/.profile was read
/home/sorontar/.bashrc was read
```

In this case, both `bashrc` files were read because each `profile` file had commands to include them, not because the login shell directly sourced them.

```
$ ssh sorontar@localhost :
/etc/bash.bashrc was read
/home/sorontar/.bashrc was read
```

In this system, where `bashrc` is read in both cases.

No need to add a `source ~/.bashrc` to the command to execute.

## Change PATH

All you need to do is include the correct settings to change the "$PATH", either in `/etc/bash.bashrc` for all users that start a shell in this system. Or in `~/.bashrc` for each user that needs it. You could add (or edit) an skeleton of an user `.bashrc` to `/etc/skel/` to have any new user created have the correct file available.

The above is valid only for bash. If you need the setting to work for all shells, probably setting the environment variable PATH using the ssh file `~/.ssh/environment` for each user that need it. Or use `/etc/ssh/sshrc` for a global setting in the system where the ssh server is running (please read the Files section in `man sshd` for some additional detail).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to execute commands (and set PATH or other environmental variables) in `~/.ssh/rc` file. From [man ssh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh):

> ~/.ssh/rc
>
> Commands in this file are executed by ssh when the user logs in, just before the user's shell (or command) is started. See the sshd(8) manual page for more information.

[sshd manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd) specifies this in its complete `Login process` description:

> 8. If ~/.ssh/rc exists, runs it; else if /etc/ssh/sshrc exists, runs it; otherwise runs xauth. The ''rc'' files are given the X11 authentication protocol and cookie in standard input. See SSHRC, below.

> The primary purpose of this file is to run any initialization routines which may be needed before the user's home directory becomes accessible; AFS is a particular example of such an environment.

This is from 2013 BSD manual. From my newer 2020 BSD manual for Arch Linux, these details are given:

> 8. If ~/.ssh/rc exists and the sshd_config(5) PermitUserRC option is set, runs it; else if /etc/ssh/sshrc exists, runs it; otherwise runs xauth.  The “rc” files are given the X11 authentication protocol and cookie in standard input. See SSHRC, below.

Probably because of this setting `~/.ssh/rc` didn't work for me.

I couldn't find at what step `sshd` runs user's login scripts. Maybe it is set in ssh configuration scripts (in this case it is distribution-dependent).

Comment: A good etiquette rule on StackExchange is to give a reason while down-voting. I looked through the question and other answers, and see no particular problem with mine. I don't think that my answer is better than others, but it has two good points: a) it is original, it proposes a new distinct solution b) it references the sources of information. If the answer is any wrong, feel free to correct that.

Comment: No idea why this was ever downvoted. This is a **great** way to set the PATH. It works both in FreeBSD and Linux (although executed twice in Linux, no idea why). Unlike `~/.profile` it's executed for both interactive and non-interactive shells. Unlike `~/.ssh/environment` you can use commands and variables like any shell script. Unlike BASH_ENV it's executed once (or twice) instead of sourced at the start of every shell script. Perfect.

Comment: oops, I spoke too soon. `~/.ssh/rc` is executed, not sourced. So you can run some commands but they will not change the env. You can't set the PATH with this.

Comment: @Daniel - many thanks for your remark! Today I don't know whether that worked for me that time and why I posted that. Maybe just read the manuals? Or could it be sourced on some environments? Maybe I shall leave this answer at the moment and upvote your comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you want one-shot behavior and your SHELL in the remote host is bash you can directly do:

```
ssh user@host "PATH=/foo/bar command"
```

If the SHELL is not bash, you can do

```
ssh user@host "bash -c 'PATH=/foo/bar command'"
```