# Some commands not found over ssh

Tags: ssh, path, macos

I'm having trouble executing some commands over ssh in localhost, I'm using zsh on mac:

```
% echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/munki:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin

% ssh localhost echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/munki:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin

% which docker
/usr/local/bin/docker

% ssh localhost which docker
docker not found
```

I don't know what could be wrong in here, tried `ssh -t` but with the same results.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the comments, it is actually different, why is that?

```
% ssh localhost printenv PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: your 2nd command confuses you. The `$PATH` is expanded before `ssh` is executed. Instead, do `ssh localhost 'echo $PATH'`.

Comment: Please show in your question the results when you use `printenv PATH` instead of `echo $PATH` in both cases.

Comment: without ssh shows the same path, ssh version added.

Comment: Found an explanation and solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332532/how-to-set-path-when-running-a-ssh-command), maybe its a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Variable interpretation is done on the command line before running any code. You could send the variable to the SSH server by escaping it or single-quoting it, e.g.

```bsh
% echo $HOST
tabasco
% ssh mesquite echo $HOST
tabasco
% ssh mesquite "echo $HOST"
tabasco
% ssh mesquite 'echo $HOST'
mesquite
% ssh mesquite echo \$HOST
mesquite
% ssh mesquite "echo \$HOST"
mesquite
% ssh mesquite 'echo \$HOST'
$​HOST
% printenv HOST
tabasco
% ssh mesquite printenv HOST
mesquite
```

(Note, not all hosts actually have a `$HOST` variable by default. BSD, for example.)