# bash: ip: command not found

Tags: centos, ssh, ip-address

I want to run for example this command : `ip addr` on my remote system. 
 I do it like this :

```
ssh username@ip ip addr
```

but I got this error :

```
bash: ip: command not found
```

when I connect to remote system and then run this command it is ok, I mean it is not caused by uninstalled package. I want to get the result without connecting permanently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

easy:
`ssh remotehost "/sbin/ip addr"`

Reason, the remote shell launched by ssh command to execute ip, have not ENV or just a basic one, and ip is not in the $PATH of the remote shell.
So either you specify the full path of the command, or you source a working environment in the remote shell before running command.

Comment: you can have a look to this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332532/how-to-set-path-when-running-a-ssh-command