# "Command not found" when using ssh and non absolute commands

Tags: shell, ssh, sshd, synology

I want to use a command over ssh:

```
ssh myuser@myhost mycommand
```

but doing so I always get:

```
sh: mycommand: command not found
```

using following obviously works:

```
ssh myuser@myhost /usr/local/bin/mycommand
```

and i understand why: it's because the command is somehow executed over a non-login shell.

Using the full command or any other parameters in my ssh command is not an option in my scenario. My command is executed by a script I cannot touch and worked on every host yet except this one.

The host that's giving me the problem is a Synology NAS and the /etc/passwd setting for that *myuser* is:

```
myuser:x:1048:100::/var/services/homes/myuser:/bin/sh
```

---

Again:

I can:

- ssh as myuser into myhost
- execute as myuser using the absolute path provided by *which
  mycommand*
- execute mycommand (non absolute) when already on myhost (via ssh)

I can't but want:

- execute: ssh myuser@myhost mycommand (non absolute, no additional
  parameters)

Comment: Linking in the related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15212/117549

Comment: I know you don't want extra parameters, but if you can relent on that requirement (and assuming your login shell is bash) -> `ssh user@host bash -lic mycommand`

Comment: -l is enough. ic makes it bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so on further investigation I noticed that on all of my other hosts mycommand is indeed in */usr/bin* **not** in */usr/local/bin*. The reason for this is, that every package manager has installed it in /usr/bin except for the weird "software store" (or whatever it is called) from synology.

I went the "dirty" way and just created a symlink: /usr/bin/mycommand > /usr/local/bin/mycommand:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/mycommand /usr/bin/mycommand
```

---

Now for everyone facing a similar problem: there is a reason why a /usr/local/bin exists and there might be risks with my solution. But it's the easiest and fastest  and I already spent way to much time on this problem. 
In my situation all ssh-keys will be limited anyways to one command only so I don't really care.

Anyways: if you want to read more about the difference between those two locations I recommend this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/308048

Answer (score 5):

Probably, your `$PATH` doesn't include `/usr/local/bin`. Since this is ssh, there are three approaches that come to mind:

1. If `PermitUserEnvironment` is enabled in the sshd config, you ought to be able to set `PATH` in `~/.ssh/environment` (that's a file in your home directory on the server — the NAS).
2. If you can edit the sshd config, then you should be able to use `SetEnv PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` (etc.) to set a path. At least if it's using OpenSSH.
3. It's possible you could use the ssh *client's* `SetEnv` option to send the server a PATH, depending on the server config. You could set this in your `~/.ssh/config` file, on your client machine.

Note that both OpenSSH server and client config files can have options limited to particular clients/servers. For example, in the client config, you could do something like this:

```
Host myhost
    SetEnv PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

to only do that for one server. Note that block continues until the next block starts (e.g, another `Host …` block) — the indenting is just for visual clarity.

OpenSSH config files are documented in the `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` manual pages.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer! Especially 1 and 2 look very promissing. I should have mentioned that I have root rights on host and can edit whatever I want. I guess that for 1 I need to set the enviroment for each user on host. I'll give it a test in a few hours when I'm back in the network.

Comment: @Simon #2 is a system-wide one, so if you need it for a bunch of users, that's probably the option you want to pick. At least if you can edit the config (no idea what Synology allows).

Comment: thanks again for your answer, I started to investigate the reason why I even have this problem to begin with and I decided to go another, more simplier but maybe also dirtier (?) way.  (see my answer)

Comment: FYI using `~/.ssh/environment` doesn't work for me at all. If I set `PATH=$PATH:...` and try `$ ssh host 'echo $PATH'`, it prints a literal `$PATH` (and anything else results in `command not found`). Explanation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60683/176219). (Both client and host are Debian FWIW.)

Comment: If you go with option (2), remember you have to restart the ssh service (i.e. `sudo systemctl restart ssh.service`)